# What is the difference between double and single quotes in pig?

Tags: apache-pig, quotes

I always thought that `''` and `""` were the same in `pig`, but today I got the

```
Unexpected character '"'
```

error on

```
register datafu-pig-1.2.1.jar
define Coalesce datafu.pig.util.Coalesce;
...
Coalesce(x,"a")
```

while

```
Coalesce(x,'a')
```

works just fine.

So, what is the difference between single and double quotes?

Comment: I checked [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/issues/?jql=project%20%3D%20DATAFU%20AND%20status%20%3D%20Open%20AND%20text%20~%20Coalesce) and didn't see any open issues with this.  What type of data does your `x` column contain?

Comment: @GoBrewers14: `chararray` of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pig doesn't support double quotes for string literals(ie chararray). All the chararray must be enclosed within single quotes.

```
A String or Chararrays are represented in interfaces by java.lang.String. 
Constant chararrays are expressed as string literals with single quotes, for example, 'fred'
```

Reference:http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001811/ch04.html#scalar_types